# How can i Use Tuckey URL Rewrite with ADF Essentials?

Tags: url-rewriting, oracle-adf

Developed on ADF 11.1.2.4 (JSF2.0 -GF 3.1.2)
Expecting to implement urlrewrite for pretty urls.
Added into web.xml:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
      <param-value>WARN</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

created urlrewrite.xml such as

```
<rule>
    <from casesensitive="false">myTest</from>
    <use-context>true</use-context>
    <to>/faces/admin/admin.jspx</to>
</rule>
```

admin.jspx contains TF.
When i deploy project and request hostname:9999/mytest redirects right page(hostname:9999/faces/admin/admin.jspx) and page renders without problem. But my actual goal was that making supply to see never real url. But i can see the real url on browser such as:(...jspx?_adf.ctrl-state=4avl71cil_1) So, what am i missing? By the way; When i type the masked url, it redirects my real page, so it works good. But seems to be the real url on browser address bar. If i only use html pages out of 'faces' context, then urlrewrite works as fully expected.
Thx, brgds

Answer (score 1):

As you have Tucky URL Rewriting filter, ADF comes with its JSF View Handler, and before ADF 12.1.x you won't be able to forward URLs unless you are using Apache Server Rewrites or Oracle HTTP Server, as the ADF internal filter will look for _adf.ctrl-state and if it's not found it'll append it to the URL which will show the actual URL of the page.

You can try to hack those _adf.ctrl-state by extending ServletRequest and when asked about _adf.ctrl-state to provide the last value saved in session, but I assure you it'll be very harmful for the application.

Comment: Many thanks for info. So, should i jump to 12c. Is it stable with glassfish 4?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no ADF Essentials for 12c yet,  so unless they release it the only way is to use Apache server with mod_rewrites