# Rewriting URL with OHS/Apache as front with Portal running on Webcenter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webcenter

We have our Portal running on Oracle Webcenter 11.1.1.8 and our WLS is fronted with OHS .
As we see , the URL to our portal page is formed as http://host:port/webcenter/portal/My-Custom-Portal/Home?.
As per out client's requirement , we are not supposed to show "webcenter/portal" in our URL along with the adf params .
What we want is URL should be clean as http://My-Custom-Portal/home and that's it.

Now,We are stuck with the URL re writing part as how to hide "webcenter/portal" . I tried editing httpd.conf file inside /config folder by adding this below rule just after where load module command for mod_rewrite.so ends.This below line of code was added as a test to see whether this works or not .

RewriteEngine on RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com

But sadly , this didn't help at all . All the request that here given to proxy host and port with webcenter were working as they were earliar .

Also read about .htaccess file that would hold the re writing rules and should be kept under the root directory . But we deploy our code as war to Weblogic , so where should the .htaccess file be kept , if at all that is needed.

What am I missing /doing wrong here .

Kind Regards,

Sid

**EDIT :** As jonathan suggested following changes were added in httpd.conf file

**Virtual host entry:**

```
NameVirtualHost *:7743
<VirtualHost *:7743>
ServerName 10.10.10.10
ServerAlias abc.abc.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule ^/mylife$ /webcenter/portal [P]
RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
<Location /webcenter>
  SetHandler weblogic-handler
  WebLogicHost 10.10.10.10
  WebLogicPort 8888
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

After hitting the url as http://10.10.10.10:7743/mylife 
we are getting the URL as

```
http://10.10.10.10:7743/mylife;jsessionid=cMDQVLyJ1QH2GqXQgNgs9PPmTmcLLqw7Lt5ctT1dgLBsvDVcBh11!-2127183939?_afrLoop=1892903079007447
```

in the address bar

with the message in the window as

```
The requested URL /mylife;jsessionid=cMDQVLyJ1QH2GqXQgNgs9PPmTmcLLqw7Lt5ctT1dgLBsvDVcBh11!-2127183939 was not found.
```

Are there any more configurations that are needed ?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is generally known as pretty URLs. There are a few different ways to achieve this.

They usually include some combination of hiding ADF parameters and also proxying/rewriting URLs.

Here are a few other links:

- http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e27603/appx_urls.htm
- http://webcenter-satishb.blogspot.com/2013/06/pretty-url-for-pages-in-webcenter.html
- https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/shorter_url_for_your_adf
- https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/pretty_url_in_adf_faces
- [How can i Use Tuckey URL Rewrite with ADF Essentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606509/how-can-i-use-tuckey-url-rewrite-with-adf-essentials)

Also, I don't recommend using Google as an example of a proxy/rewrite. Use a lesser technologically savvy website. Google does some things to prevent users from proxying.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan , Thanks!                                                                                    Added edit above of what we tried and what results we got . Any clues to solve the above issue

Answer (score 0):

Try `[R]` instead of `[p]` at the end.